# Source code not changed, but everytime I rebuild the project(Visual Studio C#), the output exe file content is different

Tags: c#, visual-studio, binary-reproducibility

I create an empty WPF project(Visual Studio 2010 or 2013, C#), and I found even I did not modify the source code, just rebuild the project, the output exe file content is different.
Can anyone tell why?

And in the same build machine, I want "When the source code not modified, what ever I rebuid the project, the rebuilt modules(dll, exe) are the same(binary content equal)"
Can anyone tell me how to obtain this target?

Comment: To help use give you a better answer, could you address why you have the requirement to get identical output modules?

Comment: Thanks Jon and c45207, through your links, I understood this problem.